# No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-emulator, android-manifest

AndroidManifest:

```
 <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logomain"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

build.gradle(Project):

```
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 26
            buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "project_name"
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 26
                versionCode 11
                multiDexEnabled true
                versionName "1.4.3"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }



    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        //noinspection GradleDependency,GradleCompatible
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'

// more stuff
}
```

bul.gradle(app):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com' }

    }
}
```

gradle.wrapper_properties:

```
#Wed Nov 07 21:38:42 PST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am using android studio 3.6 and getting error No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory'
on AndroidManifest when I'm trying to run the app on emulator with given config. I tried using `google()` in build.gradle but nothing seems to work on android studio 3.6, please suggest correct configs of gradle and manifest to run the app on emulator.